# Sequelize: Filling virtual data types after model build/create

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I have model (`Item`) with this fields:

```
id: {
    type: Sequelize.UUID,
    defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
    unique: true,
    primaryKey: true
},
item_key: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
    validate: {
        validType(value) {
            if (!items[value]) {
                throw new Error(`Wrong item key: ${value}.`);
            }
        }
    }
},
count: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    defaultValue: 1,
    allowNull: false
},
    type: {
        type:  Sequelize.VIRTUAL(Sequelize.STRING)
},
    name: {
    type:  Sequelize.VIRTUAL(Sequelize.STRING)
}
```

And `Inventory` model with assotation:

```
models['Inventory'].hasMany(
    models['Item'],
    {
        as: 'content',
        foreignKey : 'inventory_id'
    }
);
```

And I want to fill virtual fields after model is constructed depending on `item_key` field. I have tried different hooks but I got problem when using method Inventory.addContent (item).
In `afterValidate(instance, options)` instance don't have `item_key` field, and `count` is default value.

So I think I have two questions, what's best solution to fill virtual fields (I wanted to make service for it anyway and propably will fill there).
Second, why after executing `addContent` method, instance of Item in hook looks like this:

```
 dataValues: { 
   id: '3024c1d7-3de9-4684-b85a-d317559e50ab',
   count: 1,
   inventory_id: '1c588944-6b43-436d-8cd9-7fb548812ba1',
   updated_at: 2018-01-16T18:23:16.623Z 
},
```

Comment: I just added constructor to Item model where im setting those virtual fields.